# How to click on link in awesomium webcontrol c#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, awesomium

I have a website that have two links in a div.
I want to click on second link which is inside that div.
Here is how website's HTML look like:

```html
<div class="title-nav-single">
    <strong></strong>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/50665">Previous</a>
    <a href="http://www.website.com/50665/3">Next</a>
</div>
```

Now I'm trying to click on the link that contains `Next`. I don't want to get link `href` value, I just want to click on the link. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xpath = GetJsSingleXpathString("//DIV[@ID=\"outbrain_widget_0\"]/preceding-sibling::DIV[3]//A[normalize-space()=\"Next\"]");
    JsFireEvent(xpath, "click");
    // webcontrol.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('title-nav-single').ElementAt(1).DomObject.click();");
}

public static string GetJsSingleXpathString(string xpath)
{
    return String.Format("document.evaluate(\"{0}\", document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue", xpath);
}

// executes javascript which fires specified event on element 
// Example: JsFireEvent("document.getElementById('my_id')", "click");
public void JsFireEvent(string getElementQuery, string eventName)
{
    webcontrol.ExecuteJavascript(@"function fireEvent(element,event) {
        var evt = document.createEvent('HTMLEvents');
        evt.initEvent(event, true, true ); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }" + String.Format("fireEvent({0}, '{1}');", getElementQuery, eventName));
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question. This "website's HTML" you posted is website loaded into Awesomium's WebControl and you want to just open these links? or do whatever else with them?

Comment: I want to click on these links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To detect if link was clicked you need to add `target="_blank"`:

```
<a href="http://www.website.com/50665/3" target="_blank">Next</a>
```

and capture this event:

```
webControl.ShowCreatedWebView += OnShowNewView;

internal static void OnShowNewView( object sender, ShowCreatedWebViewEventArgs e )
{
    // Do sth with your link. it's in e.TargetURL
}
```

finally, you can open it with traditional way:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(e.TargetURL.ToString());
```

..or do whatever else you want to do with it. More information you can find [here](http://docs.awesomium.net/?tc=E_Awesomium_Core_IWebView_ShowCreatedWebView)